# Unable to recognize text with 100 % accuracy in a jpg file using Tess4J

Tags: ffmpeg, tesseract

I want to split a .flv video file into .jpg/png frames of good resolution & then want to recognize the character sequence in it using Tess4J tool (JNA wrapper around Tesseract).

Currently I tried the ffmpeg command line tool to split the .flv video file into jpg images.The ffmpeg command I used is:

ffmpeg -i myinput.flv myoutput%d.jpg

It is giving me the output image having the detail:

Image Dimensions : 1280 * 696

Horizontal resolution: 96 dpi

Vertical resolution:  96 dpi

bit depth: 24

My Problem is:
I tried to recognize the characters in the video frames(jpg image files which i splitted) using the following code snippet using Tess4J, it is recognizing the characters,  but not identifying with 100 % accuracy. It is adding some junk characters as well which is not there in the image.

Java code snippet I am using:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException; 

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

public class TesseractDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File imageFile = new File("D:\\myinput1.jpg");

    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();

    // Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();

    try {

        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);

        System.out.println(result);

        // write in a file
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\myoutput1.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            out.write(result);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

    } catch (TesseractException ep) {
        System.err.println(ep.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Note: In Tess4J site they have told that the image you are using for doing OCR should be of more than 200 dpi(dot per inch). How to get the jpg image of more than 200 dpi using ffmpeg ??

Any body having any java code snippet or any suggestion in this regard please help.

Comment: If you must use jpg output then consider adding `-qscale:v 2` as an output option to increase output file quality. The default settings may not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I surely will do this.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of exact command syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use PNG image format, if possible, as JPEG may have compressions and introduce artifacts. You can rescale your images in Java to the desirable resolutions (check [ImageHelper.getScaledInstance](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/159/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/src/net/sourceforge/vietocr/ImageHelper.java) method in Tess4J). You should get better results than from the original converted images. Color inversion to get black text on white background would also help.